# When i want to get a value out of a combo-box and put it as a Stroke of a Ellipse my program crashes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, graphics

The Error Page says: "The application is in break Mode"

Getting the Color of the ColorPicker and using it as Background for the Ellipse is working just fine.

My XAML Code:

.

```
<Window x:Class="FirstApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FirstApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Neuer Name" Name="txtName"/>
    <Button  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="Kopieren" Name="btnKopieren" Click="btnKopieren_Click"
             />
    <Slider Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="slRadius"
            Maximum="200" />
    <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" 
             Fill="{Binding ElementName=colorPicker, Path=HexadecimalString}"
             Stroke="{Binding ElementName=lstFarben, Path=SelectedValue}"
             Height="{Binding ElementName=slRadius, Path=Value}"  
             Width="{Binding ElementName=slRadius, Path=Value}"/>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" >
        <ComboBox x:Name="lstFarben">
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi1" Content="#0061ff" />
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi2" Content="#00ff04" />
            <ComboBoxItem Name="cbi3" Content="#ff0019" />

        </ComboBox>
        <xctk:ColorCanvas  Name="colorPicker" />
    </StackPanel>


    <Label   Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
             Content="{Binding ElementName=lstFarben, Path=SelectedValue}" Name="lblNameGross"/>





</Grid>
```

Here a Screenshot of the Error:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toqOY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are explicitly creating ComboBoxItems, the color value has to be retrieved from their `Content` property.

Set the `SelectedValuePath` property of the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="lstFarben" SelectedValuePath="Content">
```

Alternatively, get the color value directly from the selected item like this:

```
Stroke="{Binding ElementName=lstFarben, Path=SelectedItem.Content}"
```

Comment: Thank u very much bro